# visualization problem of dilution of enthalpy $\Delta_{dil} H$ data with different initial concentrations

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, enthalpy

### description

I have a question about the $m_f$ *vs*. $\Delta_{\text{dil}} H$  plot in some experimental studies.

For example, the dilution-of-enthalpy data at 300 °C with two initial concetration ($m_i$) 0.2470 and 0.5199 are reported as follows:

- $m_i$: initial concentration
- $m_f$: final concentration

[image]

then the author did the visualization by using $m_f$ *vs*. $\Delta_{\text{dil}} H$ like this:

[image]

however, when I try to do the same, I got:

[image]

it seems that the author explained a little under the diagram:

> At each temperature, a constant was added to the
> heats of dilution for the solution with the lower initial concentrations so that the zero value for these
> solutions would correspond to the zero value of the solution having a higher initial concentration

but it is not very clear to me, could anybody explain a little bit about this? How a constant could be determined for all the enthalpies of solutions with lower initial concentrations?

### reference

Oscarson, J. L., Gillespie, S. E., Chen, X., Schuck, P. C., & Izatt, R. M. (2001). Enthalpies of Dilution of Aqueous Solutions of HCl, MgCl2}, CaCl2, and BaCl2 at 300, 325, and 350° C. Journal of solution chemistry, 30, 31-53.